# How to generate custom mini-batches using Tensorflow 2.0, such as those in the paper "In defense of the triplet loss"?

Tags: python, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0, mini-batch

I want to implement a custom mini-batch generator in Tensorflow 2.0 using tf.data.Dataset API. Concretely, I have image data, 100 classes with ~200 examples each. For each mini-batch, I want to randomly sample P classes, and K images from each class, for a total of P*K examples in a mini-batch (as described in the paper [In Defense of the Triplet Loss for Person Re-Identification](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.07737.pdf)]).

I've been searching through documentation for [tf.data.Dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset), but can't seem to find the right method. I've looked into the `from_generator` method, but it doesn't seem suitable for this, since it generates a whole dataset from scratch as I understood.

It seems to me that one way to do it would be to make a new class similar to `BatchDataset` which can be found in [tf.data.Dataset source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.0/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py#L90-L1536), where I would somehow implement the logic, but I'm hoping for an easier solution to be honest.

Comment: Did u find a way? Trying the same thing myself.