# How do I generate custom batch data in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have a train data (dataframe format) like this:

```py
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4], 
    'feature': [23,24,25,23,23,22,26,27,21,22,20,23,22], 
    'label': [0,1,2,1,0,1,4,5,0,2,3,1,2]}
)
```

```
    date  feature  label
0      1       23      0
1      1       24      1
2      1       25      2
3      1       23      1
4      2       23      0
5      2       22      1
6      2       26      4
7      3       27      5
8      3       21      0
9      3       22      2
10     3       20      3
11     4       23      1
12     4       22      2
```

And I want to generate data batches where each batch only contains at most two date, for example, if batch_size=2, then a generated batch may like this:

```
   date  feature  label
0     1       23      1
2     1       25      2
```

or this:

```
   date  feature  label
0     3       27      5
2     3       22      2
```

and this:

```
   date  feature  label
0     1       23      0
2     2       22      1
```

So the current method in tensorflow like `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices` cannot meet my demand, and `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator` seem also cannot control data in batch, is there any way to self-define to `batch()` method to generate batch data?

A similar question can be found there: [How to generate custom mini-batches using Tensorflow 2.0, such as those in the paper "In defense of the triplet loss"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57570385/how-to-generate-custom-mini-batches-using-tensorflow-2-0-such-as-those-in-the-p)
,this question is also left unsolved.

I'll be really really appreciated if you can help me, thanks!!!

Comment: How is `from_tensor_slices` not working for your data?

Comment: Because from what I know `from_tensor_slices` only create a dataset, but it cannot manipulate how batch is generate. I want in each batch data only comes from at most two dates.